# Adding Event listener Function through C# but still missing it

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I am getting strange behvaiour I don't know Why? I am adding function at Add listener on button click event but still its is missing as I reload my scene. I have this function. *(Its getting desired button object correctly i have tested)*

```
 public void SetupMenuSceneButtons()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("BtnStartHost"))
            Debug.Log("BtnStartHost found");
        if (GameObject.Find("BtnJoinGame"))
            Debug.Log("BtnJoinGame found");

        GameObject.Find("BtnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find("BtnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { StartupHost(); });
        GameObject.Find("BtnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find("BtnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { JoinGame(); });

    }
```

I am calling above function on **OnLevelWasLoaded** event but its function assignment on click is still missing and my buttons are not working as i reload my scene. I have also tried Add event listener without delegate but same problem.

```
 GameObject.Find("BtnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(JoinGame);
```

I have also tried assignment through this but still problem persist.

```
GameObject.Find("BtnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find("BtnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(()=> { StartupHost(); });
        GameObject.Find("BtnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find("BtnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { JoinGame(); });
```

Comment: Do you actually get the printing indicating the button was found? You could try to invoke right after to see if it registers.

Comment: @Everts yes i am getting the button object correctly. but how do i invoke onClick through code?

Comment: GameObject.Find("BtnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();

Comment: @Everts Ok let me check it and inform you

Comment: @Everts yes invoke working correctly

Comment: @Everts  OnLevelWasLoaded running twice.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a test of your code on v5.5, OnLevelWasLoaded is just not called and triggers a warning for being deprecated (funny it still autocomplete in VS).

The following is working:

```
 void OnEnable()
 {
     SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded; ;
 }

private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
{
    SetupMenuSceneButtons();
}
```